# Как сделать превью/картинку под текстом в Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

[image: Как сделать чтобы бот отправил фотографию под сообщением без видимой гиперссылки]

Мой отрывок кода:

```
    dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Все новости"))
async def get_all_news(message: types.Message):      
    with open("news_dict.json") as file: 
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items()):
        news = f"<b>{v['article_title']}\n</b>" \
               f"<i>{v['article_desc']}\n</i>" \
               f"<a href='{v['article_img']}'></a>"  # Моя попытка сделать это
        await message.answer(message.chat.id, news)  # Отправка сообщения пользователю
```

Ссылка на изображение хранится в отдельном json файле, оттуда оно берется и должно отправляться пользователю в виде превью с сообщением.
Щас при попытке отправить сообщение вылазит ошибка:

```
    Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Unsupported parse_mode')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/tg_bot.py", line 33, in get_all_news
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, news)  # Отправка сообщения пользователю
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/types/message.py", line 397, in answer
    return await self.bot.send_message(
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 341, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/TGBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы скрыть ссылку есть функция в аиограме `hide_link`
(если что, он просто вставляет нулевой пробел и добавляет к нему ссылку).
Также не забудьте поставить `parse_mode="HTML"`.

```
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hide_link

@dp.message(commands=["hidden_link"])
async def cmd_hidden_link(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(
        f"{hide_link('https://telegra.ph/file/562a512448876923e28c3.png')}"
        f"Документация Telegram: *существует*\n"
        f"Пользователи: *не читают документацию*\n"
        f"Груша:", "HTML"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
news = "[hidden link](https://www.5.ua/dv/avtotekhno/290301)"
await msg.answer(news, parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
```

Comment: Это да, но что по поводу превью?

Comment: @PhonikTop Ну так просто ссылку нужно в текст кидать вроде

Comment: да, но гиперссылка видна же

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы саму ссылку не было видно?

Comment: @PhonikTop обновил, попробуйте